# amchart microline displays the chart out of boundary

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm using amchart's Microline chart to display some values ranging from 0 to 50000 or more. But when it reaches the zero value, it displays the chart out of the boundary (As you can see in the screenshot).

How can I fix it? I've tried changing the margins but they didn't help.

[amchart microline chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVLRc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to fix this due to how the AmCharts library handles smoothed lines internally. As a workaround, you can try setting your minimum to a small negative value that gives the curve enough space to not appear cut off when it curves below zero.